# Mockito: return NULL on X call

Tags: java, mockito

I have to mock `BufferedReader` to return values I want:

```
BufferedReader readerMock = mock(BufferedReader.class);
when(readerMock.readLine())
  .thenReturn("firstLine")
  .thenReturn("secondLine")
  .thenReturn(null);

for (String next = reader.readLine(); next != null; next = reader.readLine())
  do something...
```

**Problem:**

```
readerMock.readLine(); //returns "firstLine" 
readerMock.readLine(); //returns "secondLine"
readerMock.readLine(); //PROBLEM: returns "secondLine" instead of NULL
```

**Question:** How to return `null` on the third call

Answer (score 3):

Works for me (Mockito 1.9.5):

```
BufferedReader readerMock = mock(BufferedReader.class);
when(readerMock.readLine())
  .thenReturn("firstLine")
  .thenReturn("secondLine")
  .thenReturn(null);

System.out.println(readerMock.readLine());
System.out.println(readerMock.readLine());
System.out.println(readerMock.readLine());
```

Output:

```
firstLine
secondLine
null
```